# How to force a signal generator to sync with an imprecise frequency near 10 MHz?

Tags: equipment, synchronisation

I would need to synchronize a function generator with a 80 +- 0.1 MHz signal source. Normally I would do it by dividing the 80 MHz signal source by 8 getting 10 MHz that I send to a 10 MHz sync link of a function generator. However, my source does not have a very precise frequency of 80 MHz and 80/8 is not equal to 10 MHz within the acceptance range of my function generator. My frequency source after division by 8 can provide something about 10 +- 0.013 MHz.

Is there some workaround how to get the function generator time-based on my frequency source?

Do some signal generators have larger acceptance for the time-base?

Comment: Hi and welcome! I've tried to summarize your question in the title so it shows up better in lists. I've also tweaked your final question since this site does not want us to discuss "shopping recommendations for specific products" (https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But it is okay to ask about an on-topic product you already have. If you include which brand/model of function generator you are starting with, it is not guaranteed but it could increase chances that someone knows or can think of modifications based on its specific circuit/chips?

Comment: Thank you for the question amendment.

Comment: Surely that depends on your function generator. Wanting to synchronize to an imprecise frequency is hardly unusual, so they must make products that do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must it be a particular "function generator"? What frequency signals do you need? Must they be phase coherent with the 80 MHz reference? Over what bandwidth?

A few suggestions that might work:

Many DDS and PLL chips / boards have a wide range of clocks, 1-25 MHz for example, you could drive them from your 80 MHz, perhaps pre-scaled, to generate phase-coherent signals at any low-ish frequency.

Two popular low cost options are the AD9850 DDS (up to 125 MHz clock, output 0-40 MHz sine or square or whatever you want, with various harmonics) and the Si5351A (up to 25MHz clock, 4 kHz to >200 MHz).
If driven from an external clock, these synthesisers will of course have no "flywheel", so any phase noise on the 80 MHz will come right out of them again, with no bandwidth limit. This is kind-of what you are asking for in the first place, but the unlimited bandwidth may be a problem for you.

Or if the 80 MHz varies slowly enough, you could build the function generator into a phase locked loop yourself - divide down the output, compare to the 80 MHz, and adjust the frequency/phase of the generator. You'd probably have to do this digitally with commands on the gpib/serial port, but it may have a DC-coupled modulation input that would work, if you set it for FM with enough deviation.

If you don't need phase coherence, you could also do it entirely open loop. 1. Lock both signal generator and frequency counter to a common 10 MHz reference, perhaps the internal ref of one of them, accuracy doesn't matter. 2. Use the frequency counter to measure the 80 MHz. 3. Have your micro adjust the signal generator to follow the small offset that it measures.

Comment: This is a very useful comment. The DDS and PLL is certainly something to consider as you propose (I was not aware of such devices before). I am just not sure, if I have a time and capacity to do the build from some raw components. 
Indeed, the frequency varies slow enough so I will think about your second proposition as well.

Comment: @LeHamburger see edit for suggestions